# How to stack equations in brackets

Tags: align, amsmath

How would I recreate this format with equation/align/pmatrix?
[image: Image of what i'm trying to recreate]

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{align}
    P(t&=11 \\ t&=13 |sex&=1  \\ education &=1 )
    \end{align} = \begin{pmatrix}
        q_{11t} & q_{12t} & 0 & 0 & q_{15t} \\
        q_{21t} & q_{22t} & q_{23t} & 0 & q_{25t} \\
        0 & q_{32t} & q_{33t} & q_{34t} & q_{35t} \\
        0 & 0 & q_{43t} & q_{44t} & q_{45t} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \label{fig:transition-intensity-matrix} 
\end{equation}
```

The content is not important, I'm just trying to get the layout! I have got this far, but I am also recieving the error:
"Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;(amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned'. \end{align}"

[image: what I've got]

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome into the TeX.SE community. An advice: The align environment does not need the equation environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First version**: I have used `spalign` package to have the vertical rule in the matrix. There are so many ways to create your image. I've inserted the fonts from the image that look like Times New Roman to me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{\hat{P}}
\spalignaugmatn[l]{1}{{t_1=11,} {\mathit{sex}=1,};{t_2=13} {\mathit{education}=1}} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
        q_{11t} & q_{12t} & 0 & 0 & q_{15t} \\
        q_{21t} & q_{22t} & q_{23t} & 0 & q_{25t} \\
        0 & q_{32t} & q_{33t} & q_{34t} & q_{35t} \\
        0 & 0 & q_{43t} & q_{44t} & q_{45t} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \label{fig:transition-intensity-matrix} 
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second version**: Peraphs this MWE it is more closer to the original image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\mathbf{\hat{P}}\biggl(\,\begin{aligned}
  & t_1=11, \\
  & t_2=13
\end{aligned}\, \Big\lvert \mkern5mu \begin{aligned}
  & \mathit{sex}=1,\\
  & \mathit{education}=1
\end{aligned}\,\biggr)=\begin{pmatrix}
        q_{11t} & q_{12t} & 0 & 0 & q_{15t} \\
        q_{21t} & q_{22t} & q_{23t} & 0 & q_{25t} \\
        0 & q_{32t} & q_{33t} & q_{34t} & q_{35t} \\
        0 & 0 & q_{43t} & q_{44t} & q_{45t} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \label{fig:transition-intensity-matrix} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Im relatively new to latex and havent heard of the spalign package before - so this was incredibly useful!

Comment: @user249034 Wait :-)...working in progress :-)

Comment: @user249034 I thank you for the green checkmark but encourage you to choose the better answer. So as well know all do not care about the votes, but rather that you learn and stay with us in this wonderful community. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \mathbf{\hat{P}}\left(
    \begin{array}{@{}l|l@{}}
        t_1=11, & \mathit{sex}=1,\\ 
        t_2=13 & \mathit{education}=1
    \end{array}\right)
    = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        q_{11t} & q_{12t} & 0 & 0 & q_{15t} \\
        q_{21t} & q_{22t} & q_{23t} & 0 & q_{25t} \\
        0 & q_{32t} & q_{33t} & q_{34t} & q_{35t} \\
        0 & 0 & q_{43t} & q_{44t} & q_{45t} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

The output image is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, there are two commas in t_1=11 and \mathit{sex}=1 :-) (missed)

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this code, based on alignedat, and a hack for the vertical line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \widehat{\mathbf{P}}\biggl(
   \begin{alignedat}{3}t&=11, &\enspace &\smash{\rule[-3.3ex]{0.6pt}{5ex}}\enspace & \text{sex}&=1,\\[-0.5ex] %
   t&=13 & & & \text{education} &=1
    \end{alignedat}\biggr) = \begin{pmatrix}
        q_{11t} & q_{12t} & 0 & 0 & q_{15t} \\
        q_{21t} & q_{22t} & q_{23t} & 0 & q_{25t} \\
        0 & q_{32t} & q_{33t} & q_{34t} & q_{35t} \\
        0 & 0 & q_{43t} & q_{44t} & q_{45t} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \label{fig:transition-intensity-matrix}
\end{equation}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is also perfect :-). There are two commas in the first matrix. After in the text you do an edit: you separe the word "thiscode" :-)

Comment: I not understood the word "hack"=tagliare in Italian language :-) cut, cut off, trim, chop, slice, hack.

Comment: Thank you for warning me, my friend. I've fixed everything (I believe). I must say I was glad of the dirty hack, so I didn't even thought of checking my post. Fortunately, you did it for me… ;o)

Comment: I believe that ’hack’, originally, means in English ‘cut (with an axe)’, so it seems to be the smae initial meaning, appled to a code. In French, we have another word, in popular language, which conveys the same meaning: the verb ‘charcuter’, but I've never seen it used for a code.